# Faces recognition using PCA and SVM, python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using the following code from an example on sklearn documentation website
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

from time import time
import logging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC

print(__doc__)

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')



# Download the data, if not already on disk and load it as numpy arrays

lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(data_home='~/Documents/git/machineLearningND/face_recognition/data', min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)

# introspect the images arrays to find the shapes (for plotting)
print (lfw_people.images.shape)
n_samples, h, w = lfw_people.images.shape

# for machine learning we use the 2 data directly (as relative pixel
# positions info is ignored by this model)
X = lfw_people.data
n_features = X.shape[1]

# the label to predict is the id of the person
y = lfw_people.target
target_names = lfw_people.target_names
n_classes = target_names.shape[0]

print("Total dataset size:")
print("n_samples: %d" % n_samples)
print("n_features: %d" % n_features)
print("n_classes: %d" % n_classes)

# Split into a training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)


# Compute a PCA (eigenfaces) on the face dataset (treated as unlabeled
# dataset): unsupervised feature extraction / dimensionality reduction

n_components = 150

print("Extracting the top %d eigenfaces from %d faces" % (n_components, X_train.shape[0]))
t0 = time()
pca = PCA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True).fit(X_train)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

print (pca.components_.shape)

eigenfaces = pca.components_.reshape((n_components, h, w))

print("Projecting the input data on the eigenfaces orthonormal basis")
t0 = time()
X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))


# Train a SVM classification model
print("Fitting the classifier to the training set")
t0 = time()
param_grid = {'C': [1e3, 5e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5], 'gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1], }

# for sklearn version 0.16 or prior, the class_weight parameter value is 'auto'
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced'), param_grid)
clf = clf.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
print("Best estimator found by grid search:")
print(clf.best_estimator_)


# Quantitative evaluation of the model quality on the test set

print("Predicting people's names on the test set")
t0 = time()
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_pca)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=range(n_classes)))


# Qualitative evaluation of the predictions using matplotlib

def plot_gallery(images, titles, h, w, n_row=3, n_col=4):
    """Helper function to plot a gallery of portraits"""
    plt.figure(figsize=(1.8 * n_col, 2.4 * n_row))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=.01, right=.99, top=.90, hspace=.35)
    for i in range(n_row * n_col):
        plt.subplot(n_row, n_col, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].reshape((h, w)), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
        plt.title(titles[i], size=12)
        plt.xticks(())
        plt.yticks(())

# plot the result of the prediction on a portion of the test set
def title(y_pred, y_test, target_names, i):
    pred_name = target_names[y_pred[i]].rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]
    true_name = target_names[y_test[i]].rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]
    return 'predicted: %s\ntrue:      %s' % (pred_name, true_name)

prediction_titles = [title(y_pred, y_test, target_names, i) for i in range(y_pred.shape[0])]

plot_gallery(X_test, prediction_titles, h, w)

# plot the gallery of the most significative eigenfaces

eigenface_titles = ["eigenface %d" % i for i inrange(eigenfaces.shape[0])]
plot_gallery(eigenfaces, eigenface_titles, h, w)

plt.show()
```

So this breaks with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eigenfaces.py", line 87, in <module>
eigenfaces = pca.components_.reshape((n_components, h, w))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

n_samples, h, w = lfw_people.images.shape
lfw_people.images.shape = (109, 50, 37)
```

so h = 50 and w = 37

and in line:
    eigenfaces = pca.components_.reshape((n_components, h, w))

```
pca.components_.shape = (81, 1850)
n_component = 150
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You should post the full stack trace. And also some face data files on which this error is occuring

Comment: Also the link about the example on the top is not working